# How to disable commenting on 'became friends with' posts?

Tags: facebook, friends

Because my friends are having fun on 'became friends with' posts (writing stupid things and such), I want to block commenting but I don't want to hide the post.

I googled and I couldn't find anything similar to this exact problem I'm having.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of blocking comments on this specific kind of posts. If you don't want specific people to see your posts, you can exclude them from the audience. Checkout [Facebook Help](https://www.facebook.com/help/211513702214269).